# KnockoutJS: Create an observable from click binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I may be over-thinking this, but what I am trying to do is to create an observableArray from a click event bound to a function. Basically, when I click on a button, I need to filter results based on `event.target.html()` and create an observable that I can use in a `foreach` loop later in the page.

First, I have a button.

```
<button data-bind="click: getData">Button Text</button>
```

Function that filters results based on Button Text

```
self.filterFunction = function(x) {
      // do things here
      return (obj);
}
```

Click is bound to the `getData` function, which calls `filterFunction` with DOM element from the click
and creates an observable array

```
self.getData = function(item, event) {
      viewModel.myFilteredData = ko.observableArray(self.filterFunction($(event.target).html()));  

}
```

And then I loop through `myFilteredData`, but fail miserably.

```
<!-- ko foreach: myFilteredData -->
       // Generate HTML here
<!-- /ko -->
```

Something tells me that I fail at logic and there is a more efficient way of doing this. I also would like to figure out a way to have `myFilteredData` pre-populated based on some pre-set `Button Text`, so the HTML can be generated on initial page load, before any buttons are clicked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem you're having is that your `foreach` binding is bound to a different observable array than the one you generate after the click. Think of it this way. Given this view model:

```
{
    myFilteredData: ko.observableArray()
}
```

...when the `ko.applyBindings` happens, Knockout subscribes to this `ko.observableArray` for updates, and loops through the (now empty) array.

Now, your click handler occurs:

```
viewModel.myFilteredData = ko.observableArray(self.filterFunction($(event.target).html()));
```

The subscription established above isn't triggered because the observable array didn't change; instead, you replaced it with another one. Unfortunately, Knockout doesn't know about the new one.

I'd recommend that instead of replacing the array with a new one, you populate the existing array with the new data:

```
viewModel.myFilteredData(self.filterFunction($(event.target).html()));
```

Comment: You're welcome. Using a computed observable as suggested by Ryan is also a fantastic idea.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just set an observableArray in your view model, create a function bound to your button click, and pass in each object?  Bind the buttons with a for each to some observables or entities, and then on button click have a parameter that you push into the observableArray

Answer (score 2):

Solefald, there's definitely a better way to do this.

First, add an array of your own "filter" objects to your view model, as well as a ko.computed to provide your filtered data.  Bind your filter buttons to the array of "filter" objects.  Something like this:

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.filters = [
        {buttonText:'Button Text', filterKey:'filterKeyOne'},
        {buttonText:'Other Button Text', filterKey:'filterKeyTwo'}
    ];
    self.selectedFilterKey = ko.observable('none');
    self.setFilter = function(){...}

    self.data = ko.observableArray([...]);
    self.filteredData = ko.computed(function(){...});
}
```

and bind like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: filters">
    <button data-bind="click : $parent.setFilter, text: buttonText"></button>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: filteredData">
    ...
</div>
```

By letting Knockout do the click binding for the filter buttons, you'll get your whole filter object as the first parameter in the "runFilter" function.  You can then implement your filter button click handler ("setFilter" in this example) like this:

```
self.setFilter = function(filterItem){
   self.selectedFilterKey(filterItem.filterKey);
};
```

By making "selectedFilterKey" an observable, you can implement your filteredData as a ko.computed which will automatically update the ui when "selectedFilterKey" changes, like this :

```
...
self.filteredData = ko.computed(function(){
    //pick the right filter function
    var filterFunction = filterOne;//assign the default filter function
    switch(self.selectedFilterKey()){
        case 'filterKeyOne':
            filterFunction = self.filterOne;//your first filter
        break;
        case 'filterKeyTwo':
            filterFunction = self.filterTwo;//your second filter
        break;
    }
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.data(), function(item){        
        //return true if item passes filter
        return filterFunction(item);
    });
});
...
```

### A Functional Approach

If you'd like to use a more functional programming approach, try defining your filter functions right in the filter objects.

```
self.filters = [
    {buttonText:'Button Text', filterFunction:function(item){...}},
    {buttonText:'Other Button Text', filterFunction:function(item){...}}
];
```

and store the selected function, rather than a key

```
self.setFilter = function(filterItem){
   self.selectedFilterFunction(filterItem.filterFunction);
};
```

and skip the switch statement

```
...
self.filteredData = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.data(), function(item){        
        //return true if item passes filter
        return self.selectedFilterFunction()(item);
    });
});
...
```

### More Information

If you'd like more info about this approach for sorting, you can read about it on my blog here : http://ryanrahlf.com/sorting-tables-by-column-header-with-knockout-js/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ryan, this is fantastic! Thank you very much. This solved many other things I have been trying to figure out

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help!  If you'd like, drop by my blog and sign up for my newsletter.  I post more like this about once a week, with special tips just to the folks on my list.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Ryan, I spoke a bit too soon... While i sorta follow what your example is doing, my understanding of Knockout and JS in general is rather limited and after spending hours on it last night, i still cant make some a connection between `filterFunction:function(){ // some code here  }}` and what this function is supposed to return? Is there an example of a filter function inside a filter object i can see somewhere? I've searched high and low, but without any success so far.

Comment: +1 Very nice post! You can pass the function directly, though in the `arrayFilter` instead of wrapping it in another function though, right?

Comment: Yes Benjamin, you absolutely could.  Good eyes.  I think I wrote it that way to mirror what I had in the section above, but the extra function wrapper isn't necessary.